# unable to convert to date time in R

Tags: r, posixct

```
structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2016-10-19 00:00:00", class = "factor")), .Names = "Datetime", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

when I try to convert Datetime to POSIXct as this:

```
t$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(t$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I lose hour, minute and second from the data. It becomes like this:

```
 Datetime
1 2016-10-19
2 2016-10-19
3 2016-10-19
4 2016-10-19
5 2016-10-19
6 2016-10-19

dput(t)
structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(1476849600, 1476849600, 
1476849600, 1476849600, 1476849600, 1476849600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = "Datetime", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

why I am losing the hour, minute seconds from the data?

Comment: I thought Matthew Lundberg answered that question previously. You did not lose it, it is just not displayed.

Comment: @aichao, I think I lose the values.

Comment: According to the documentation (see `?DateTimeClasses`): Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC time zone) as a numeric vector. These are what the rather large integer values in your last `dput()` represent.

Answer (score -1):

You are not loosing it, they are just not displayed (since 00:00:00 means no significant time). Try setting values for hour, minutes and seconds, they will be displayed.

```
t <- structure(list(
  Datetime = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  .Label = "2016-10-19 00:00:00", 
  class = "factor")), 
  .Names = "Datetime", 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
  class = "data.frame")

t$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(t$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

head(t, 3)
#             Datetime
# 1 2016-10-19 01:01:01
# 2 2016-10-19 01:01:01
# 3 2016-10-19 01:01:01

str(t)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ Datetime: POSIXct, format: "2016-10-19 01:01:01" "2016-10-19 01:01:01" ...
```

I suggest using the [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) package to manage dates, it is easy to use and less error prone. The following code gives the same result.

```
library(lubridate)

t$Datetime <- ymd_hms(t$Datetime)
```